# Inequality with square root and squaring each side of the inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

My book says if I take $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \lt 1,\;$ and it says if I "square each side of the inequality" the result will give the inequality $\;x^2 + y^2\lt 1,\;$ but I don't understand the concept.

If you find the square root of $5^2$ isn't that $5$?

Then isn't the square root of $\,x^2 + y^2\,$ equal to $\,x + y\;?$

Am I thinking about this correctly or am I mistaken somehow?

Comment: You're going to need to write out the whole thing. You haven't written any inequality.

Comment: @Jessica To get $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ type \$\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\$.

Comment: @dfeuer $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} < 1$

Comment: $(x + y)^2$ is not equal to $x^2 + y^2$ – try e.g. $x = 1$ and $y = 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please understand: While it **is true** that $\;\sqrt{(x + y)^2} = x+y,\,$ note that $$
\begin{align} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} & \color{blue}{\;\large \bf \neq\;}x + y \\ \\
\text{so}\quad \left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 & \neq (x + y)^2 \\ \\
\text{because}\quad x^2 + y^2 & \neq x^2 + 2xy + y^2
\end{align}$$

Regarding your inequality (for why I'm addressing this, please note the OP's comment below, and the fact that the original post before editing, included a statement about being perplexed as to why the following is true):
$$\begin{align} \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \lt 1 & \implies \left(\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\right)^2 \lt (1)^2\\ \\ & \implies x^2 + y^2 \lt 1\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm thinking about it but nothing is happening in my head.

Comment: amWhy, I'm trying really hard to understand where you came up with that guess for what inequality JessicaM might have intended, and am coming up blank.

Comment: @dfeuer I delayed my upvote for the same reason, I just can't see it.

Comment: My guess for the moment is that amWhy has read every popular middle school, high school, and undergraduate math text and remembers all the exercises.

Comment: yes the $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ < 1 is equal to x^2 + y^2 < 1. That is the formula I had a question about

Comment: Okay, I'll repost: @dfeur Please see Jessica's comment immediately above!

Comment: @amWhy I've read it, the thing is, way before the OP hinted about the inequality $(<1)$, you had already assumed that that was what she was talking about.

Comment: @GitGud I knew it from her original post! Before five minutes were up, she had edited it!! I wouldn't have pulled that out of thin air!

Comment: For this problem it's probably overkill, but one could note that applying any increasing function (which of course $x^2$ is) to both sides of an inequality will respect the original inequality, as long as both sides are in the range of the increasing function.

Comment: @amWhy Ah! That explains it.

Comment: @AmWhy abd Git Gud sorry didn't mean to edit the question and change it up on you guys I just thought the question didn't make sense at first.

Comment: @Jessica. A neater way to handle edits to a question is to mark the changes, often by adding **Edit:** That way, the context of pre-edit and post-edit answers/comments will be clear to later readers.

Comment: Don't worry about it. All's well that ends well ;-)

Comment: @RickDecker Great suggestion. I'll definitely do that next time

Comment: @Jessica. Thanks. May all your subsequent posts not need editing.

Comment: Thanks everyone. This is just a simple concept I don't know how i got confused. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: @amWhy: Well, this generated some interesting comments :-) +1

Comment: @amWhy thanks for the answer gain. The last part answered my question exactly. It's so simple I don't understand why I didn't get if you square both sides you get rid of the square root.

Comment: You're welcome, Jessica! Sometimes we all overlook what later seems more obvious!